# Highcharts exporting.js change menu hover title text

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and I've added exporting.js so I can export data.

This makes a menu appear which has a title of "Chart context menu".

See image attached:

[image]

You can also see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/):

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'female'
        }, {
            name: 'Janet',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'female'
        }]
    });
});
```

My question is..How can I change the title text so it says something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is an option to change the title via API but you need to set it in the global options - [lang.contextMenuTitle](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.contextButtonTitle)

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    contextButtonTitle: 'custom text'
  }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/1zmwjskz/

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation there is currently no option to do that [- details of the available options are listed here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton). But you can always use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("g.highcharts-contextbutton > title").text("Something else");
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz1Lrayf/1/).